# Adding general page content to page templates

Tags: page-template, loop

If I'm creating a page template, let's say for example one for a testimonials custom post type I've created, I think I have it figured out that if I do the following in page-testimonials.php:

```
    <?php get_template_part('loop', 'page'); ?>
    <?php get_template_part('loop', 'testimonials'); ?>
```

Then that will output the content of the page itself and then go into the testimonials loop to grab a list of the most recent testimonials, etc.

I'm having trouble doing the same for a page that is called from WP Settings as the "Posts Page". Let's say at the top of the "Blog" page (a WordPress page), I want some intro text to the blog that says, "Welcome to the blog. Please check out new posts below." Instead of hardcoding that into the template, how would that be achieved? Am I even thinking of how actual page content is displayed depending on if a custom page template is chosen? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm having trouble doing the same for a page that is called from WP Settings as the "Posts Page". Let's say at the top of the "Blog" page (a WordPress page), I want some intro text to the blog that says, "Welcome to the blog. Please check out new posts below." Instead of hardcoding that into the template, how would that be achieved?

First, understand that, per the [WordPress Template Hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy), the template files used in this context are, in order of preference: `home.php`, and `index.php`. Nothing you do to a *custom page template* will have any impact on what WordPress uses to render the *Blog Posts Index*.

Your best solution here would be to hard-code this text into `home.php`, outside the Loop. You could put this text inside a template-part file, and call it via `get_template_part( $foobar )` if you really wanted to, but doing so honestly serves no purpose here.

By the way: what is your aversion to hard-coding template-specific text into a template file?

p.s. here is [a more current version of the Template Hierarchy](http://www.chipbennett.net/themes/template-hierarchy/). (I'll be adding it to the Codex shortly.)

**EDIT**

> I am working on a theme that will be distributed/available to dozens, if not hundreds of different clients. I'd like clients to be able to control if there is any intro text within the blog area.

I really don't think you can output the `$post->post_content` for the static Page used as `page_for_posts`. Maybe you could use a custom query, e.g. using [`get_page()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page):

```
<?php
$page_for_posts = get_page( get_option( 'page_for_posts' ) );
$page_for_posts_content = $page_for_posts->post_content;
echo apply_filters( 'the_content', $page_for_posts_content );
?>
```

Alternately, I would suggest one of two approaches:

1. Create a **Theme Option** to define this text/content
2. Make that part of the template file a **dynamic sidebar**, and let users add a Widget - e.g. a Text Widget - in which they can define this text/content

Comment: Hi @Chip,
Really appreciate the quick response. The main reason for not hard-coding in static text is because I am working on a theme that will be distributed/available to dozens, if not hundreds of different clients. I'd like clients to be able to control if there is any intro text within the blog area.

I am correct in how I was doing "other" custom page templates? I understand the "Posts Page" setting in WordPress seems to override any page template called, but do you agree that it seems weird you can't put any intro text before this area is called from a page? Thanks!

Comment: @Zach see updated answer; I've added three options.

Comment: H*** crap @Chip I think you did it ha. The first option (with grabbing the page that is set as the page_for_posts) worked great! Honestly can't see a downside to this... seems like it'd give some extra flexibility to this area. Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: Glad it worked! That was a stab in the dark. :)

Comment: Ouch. `get_page()` is now deprecated.